# Replace the word "real time"

Tags: javascript, ajax

I made a javascript function to find a word in html component and replace it with another word. However, it could do was to insert a button that when clicked invoke the function to replace the words.

I wonder if anyone knows of a way to do this in "run-time" in the case, when you type a word that should be replaced, it be replaced without having to click the button.

Follows the code to find and replace the words:

```
var texto = document.getElementById("cadastroLaudo:transcript").value;
var novoParagrafo = texto.replace(/novo paragrafo/g, '\n');

document.getElementById('cadastroLaudo:transcript').value = novoParagrafo;
```

My HTML component that will receive the substitution of the word to be found (code below):

```
<p:inputTextarea id="transcript" name="transcript" rows="8"
        cols="60" placeholder="Ditado para Geração de Laudo Médico"
        value="#{laudoBean.laudo.texto}" />
```

And the button that calls the javascript function:

```
<p:commandButton onclick="formatarTextoLaudo()" value="Formatar" />
```

In summary, the component  is a text box when you type "novo paragrafo" is inserted Enter and the word "novo paragrafo" disappears.

It would be something with Ajax?

Tks!

Comment: You're looking for the change or key events.

Comment: do you mean like adding an event listener for keyUp?

Comment: there are multiple ways: onChange, onInput, onKeyUp, etc... you can bind events in your html, or using javascript, or jQuery

Comment: Is it a `contenteditable` element the user is editing, is it an `input` tag? You have to specify more for us to help you fully

Comment: `input` would be the most correct event to listen to here.

Comment: I edited the question with more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would detect when user press space, then check if the word needs to be replaced

```
$('body').keyup(function(e){   
   if(e.keyCode == 32){
       // user has pressed space
       //change word function           
   }
});
```

Comment: Tks! It worked very well! Whenever squeeze the space bar, calls the function to replace the word :)